# expected expression before -return value-

Tags: c

Given the following function:

```
image_ret* minify_1(image_src img_src, CLIENT* cl) {
  image_ret* img_ret;
  magickminify_init();
  magickminify(img_src.image_src_val, img_src.image_src_len, (ssize_t*)&img_ret->image_ret_len);
  return image_ret;
}
```

The compiler is telling me "expected expression before ‘image_ret’" with regard to the last line. I'm sure I'm missing some fundamental aspect of syntax here, but I don't know what. Lil' help?

Comment: `return image_ret;` --> `return img_ret;`. Type name vs variable name.

Comment: Well that must be embarrassing.

Comment: Ha ha ha. What can I say? I've been looking at this for way too long.

Comment: LOL, next time you get tired, and you've looked at something like this over, and over again, copy/paste the local var name to the return value.  It's amazing how copying a string over an 'identical' string can somehow make stuff work:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value, not a type. `image_ret` is a type, `img_ret` is a poitner to a value of that type and probably what you want to return, except I see nowhere in your code where you allocate any storage to it, or initialising any of the fields except `image_ret_len`